# Get name of brand based on brand ID

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have one table with a similar structure:

```
ID  |  NAME      |  BRAND_ID
--------------------------------
22  | Phone1     |  2
25  | Cereal     |  9
33  | Cereal     |  4
39  | Water      |  3
```

Also I have a brand's table:

```
ID  |  NAME
--------------------
2   |  PhoneMaker
9   |  CerealEaters
3   |  WaterDoers
```

When the user does a search, I execute this query and show the results

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
WHERE `name` COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI LIKE '%$user_search%'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

What I need is that **the user is able to search ALSO with the brand name**.

Example: User writes "Phone", so he finds "Phone1".

Example 2: User is looking for the "CerealEaters" brand, so the results show "Cereal" (id 25) and also "CerealEaters".

How can I connect that brand id with the brand name when the user is searching in the "products" table?

Comment: Why not use a simple join query ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN brands b
    ON p.BRAND_ID = b.ID
WHERE p.name COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI LIKE '%$user_search%' OR
      b.name COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI LIKE '%$user_search%'
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` here may be beneficial in the case where a product, for some reason, has no matching brand.  In this case, the search against brand name would fail, but the search against the product name might still match.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `brands` ON `products`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`name` COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI LIKE '%$user_search%'
   OR `brands`.`name` COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI LIKE '%$user_search%'
ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected query is bellow with `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT * FROM products a left join brands b on a.BRAND_ID =  b.ID 
WHERE a.NAME COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI like '%$user_search%' 
or b.NAME COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI like '%$user_search%'
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
```